# how can I json_encode an object to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, json, serialization

I'm trying to json_encode an object but I want the external wrapper to be an array not an object.

I've tried

`json_encode($myObject, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY)`

But my end result is always

```json
{
  "SALDOC": [
    {
      "SERIES": null,
      "TRDR": null,
      "PAYMENT": "2",
      "SHIPMENT": "",
      "TRNDATE": "2019-03-11 07:57:38",
      "REMARKS": null,
      "DISC1VAL": "0.0000",
      "SALESMAN": null,
      "SHIPKIND": null,
      "CCCCLCOURIERWEIGHT": "1.0000"
    }
  ],
  "ITELINES": [
    {
      "LINENUM": null,
      "VAT": null,
      "MTRUNIT4": null,
      "MTRCATEGORY": null,
      "MTRL": null,
      "QTY1": "1.0000",
      "PRICE": "15.0000"
    }
  ],
  "MTRDOC": [
    {
      "SHPZIP": "test",
      "SHPCITY": "teset",
      "SHIPPINGADDR": "test",
      "SHPDISTRICT": 100
    }
  ],
  "SRVLINES": [],
  "EXPANAL": []
}
```

How can I make the outer wrapping to be an array [] instead of an object {}?

Comment: You can't, because it contains key-value pairs. Convert it to an simple array before encoding it.

Comment: I've tried casting the object to an array first like (array)$myObject but this failed too. Do I need to do something specific to make it work?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: If it's an array in JSON then you won't have `SALDOC` keys etc...

Comment: I see. OK I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

If i guess something like you are trying to convert an object to an array right ? so you can use :

$get_array = json_decode(json_encode($myObject), true);
return $get_array;